# Passing data from controller to component in ember js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have situation where a have component that with send a function to the controller and the data is computed in controller.Again I need to send the resultant of the function to the component and do the rest of the computation.As a beginner Im encountering it .Is it possible to do so?

I tried it to pass as a variable but it is getting a empty list

Comment: hello! can you add the code you've tried so far to your question? it'd be a huge help!